# Why are anonymous methods faster in my tests?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I wrote two simple applications:
     1. one using anonymous methods, and
     2. one using simple methods.

Each of the methods above are doing a simple action:

```
int add(int n1, int n2) {return n1+n2}
```

And I call a simple `for` loop that will call the `add` method 10,000 times. The implementation using anonymous methods takes much less time than the other. Why? Is it because the JITter inlines anonymous methods?

```
delegate int ADD( int i1, int i2 );

private  void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Reset();

        watch.Start();

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++ )
        {
            add( i, i );
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Normal Call " + watch.ElapsedTicks);

        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++ )
        {
            ADD p = delegate( int n1, int n2 )
            {
                return n1 + n2;
            };

            p.Invoke( i, i );
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine( watch.ElapsedTicks );

        Console.ReadLine();


    } 

    int add(int n1, int n2)
    {
        return n1 + n2;
    }
 }
```

The result - on release mode - compile on x64 ( pressed on the action button couple of times ):

```
Normal 1525
1275
Normal 480
477
Normal 371
370
Normal 372
371
Normal 477
479
Normal 477
477
Normal 564
702
Normal 478
476
```

Comment: Only 1000 times? Any modern computer can do that in less than a millisecond. On the other hand, the clock in your computer has a hard time measuring intervals that small. Please post your timing code.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to answer this question. Are you in release or debug mode for one.

Comment: i used the Stopwatch to Console.Write the time that took the loop to run - on release & debug using the 'anonymous methods' was fester then the regular method.

Comment: Are you running inside or outside Visual Studio? A debugger will prevent JIT optimizations (and distort the results) even in Release configuration. Also, does `add` happen to be declared in an interface and then implemented in the class, or it's just a straight class-level method?

Comment: i know about the JIP optimizations ... i talking about release mode

Comment: I bet you're reading the output wrong. On my computer I get results like `21 236`, meaning the `add` method is 10 times faster than the anonymous delegate. When I compile for x64, the method probably gets inlined and ends up being nearly 100x faster!

Comment: SO => finally .. are the anonymous methods is something that make the code fester ? are they give better performance ? if 'no' so why to use them ?

Comment: @Yanshof: Anonymous delegates exist to make code more concise and for making closures, not to make the code faster (or fester, for that matter).

Comment: Please see my code fix - the 'notmal' call of the method is slower usually.

Comment: @Yanshof: You should paste some sample output of your updated program, because none of us here believe you.

Comment: add to the question budy. and run it again with the fixing code that i add above.

Comment: That "action button" that you're pressing -- it's the "Start Debugging" button. In other words, you're running your program (compiled in Release mode) under the debugger. If you run it from the command line you'll see that it goes much faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not confirm your results.

In my testing, the "normal" function performs about order of magnitude better than the delegate. Here is your slightly modified code that I used for testing:

```
class Program {

    delegate int ADD(int i1, int i2);

    static int add(int n1, int n2) {
        return n1 + n2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();

        const int count = 100000;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            add(i, i);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);

        ADD p = delegate(int n1, int n2) {
            return n1 + n2;
        };

        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            p.Invoke(i, i);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);

    }

}
```

This prints:

```
103
1321
```

You must be doing something that skews the results.

**--- EDIT ---**

OK I've done another round of testing, this time with a WinForms application.

- When WinForms application is compiled as 'x86', the results are the same as the console application above (function is faster than delegate).
- When WinForms is compiled as 'x64', the function slows-down dramatically, roughly to the level of the delegate.
- When function is made `static`, it speeds-up again (in 'x64' WinForms build).
- The console application above never slows-down, even in 'x64' build and even when function is made non-static.

Everything was measured outside debugger in Release configuration.

Comment: I don't think he's skewing the results; I think he's reading it wrong and thinking that the top line is the result for delegates and the bottom line for methods.

Comment: No - please see my fixing the code - and try to run it again ! The 'normal' code is run slower !

Comment: @Yanshof Is this WinForms or console application?

Comment: winform - ( the action is by button press )_

Comment: @Yanshof Then why you have `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: @Branko: The problem is actually that he's running his program under the debugger. If you set the build to Release mode, the platform target to x64, and press F5, you should get similar results.

Comment: @Gabe No, I've actually confirmed his results (see the edit). There is something weird going on in the 'x64' build of the WinForms application.